# apt-fast for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lts, apt-fast

I just upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 from ubuntu 12.04 (Which I loved) and now, I cant install apt-fast. My net connection is very slow and I want to download using apt-fast but whenever I add the apt-fast ppa and update and try to install it, It says

`package apt-fast not found`

How do I fix this? thank you.

I really appreciate The effort made by askubuntu (Which includes you awesome people ;)) To help me. My problem has already been answered. Here is a screenshot of my software sources. The person who answered my question has apparently removed the comment that answered my question but here is the repository that helped me add apt-fast

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/myppa`

So if this helps I would like to upvote each and every person who helped me and I will accept one answer too, Just give me some time to test both of them ;)

anyway thank you guys to help me. You are awesome :-) XD

Comment: It's installed.Thank you. Please post that as an answer so that I can accept it. I would also like to know that if there is a way to make ubuntu software center use apt-fast instead of apt-get.

Comment: you can install apt-fast v1.8, check this https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you my be misunderstanding the purpose of apt-fast.  It's not something for slow network connections, it's something for fast network connections.  If you have a slow connection to the Internet, you are not reaching the bottleneck of the repository and will not benefit by pulling from more than one repository simultaneously.

If you have a fast Internet connection, faster than the repositories, then you could benefit by pulling from more than one repository at once.

More directly to your question, did you run the `sudo apt-get update` after adding the repository?

In between asking the question I tried the repository on a test machine and it appears to be broken (for ubuntu/trusty 14.04).  What error did you get when you tried to update the repository?

Alternatively, with the apt-fast repository broken you can use the [github](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast).

You might also communicate the broken (or unavailable 14.04) repository to the apt-fast support team.

With the knowledge that you can't benefit from it on a machine with a slow Internet connection might be a factory in how much work you want to invest in installing it on your computer.

Comment: There are now two different apt-fast repositories for Ubuntu 14.04, so you could try using the other one (the repository for trusty and utopic).

Comment: The apt-fast repository for trusty and utopic hasn't been updated since Ubuntu 14.10 Alpha 2. Hopefully by the time you use it, it will have been updated to a stable release version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @karel Thanks for the updated information, Karel.  I noticed I had typed comment responses intended for Jatin to you.  I'm correcting that now by removing the mis-directed comments.

Comment: @JatinKaushal Thanks for the expression of appreciation. The comment changed while I was performing research to test and verify my answer.  I spent about a half hour researching and testing my answer and suggestions while making the post. You don't have to accept the answer, but at the time of my research and posting (which again, took about a half hour) there weren't an answer.  By the way, you can repair the integrity of your repository list by removing the failed one with: `sudo add-apt-repository remove ppa:apt-fast/stable`

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot upvote as I don't have enough reputuation

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

1. Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run it:

   sudo nano /usr/bin apt-fast

Paste these lines:

```
-------------------------------
# !/bin/sh
# apt-fast v0.03 by Matt Parnell http://www.mattparnell.com, this thing is fully open-source
# if you do anything cool with it, let me know so I can publish or host it for you
# contact me at admin@mattparnell.com

# Special thanks
# Travis/travisn000 - support for complex apt-get commands
# Allan Hoffmeister - aria2c support
# Abhishek Sharma - aria2c with proxy support
# Richard Klien - Autocompletion, Download Size Checking (made for on ubuntu, untested on other distros)
# Patrick Kramer Ruiz - suggestions - see Suggestions.txt
# Sergio Silva - test to see if axel is installed, root detection/sudo autorun

# Use this just like apt-get for faster package downloading.

# Check for proper priveliges
[ "`whoami`" = root ] || exec sudo "$0" "$@"

# Test if the axel is installed
if [ ! -x /usr/bin/axel ]
then echo "axel is not installed, perform this?(y/n)"
    read ops
    case $ops in
         y) if apt-get install axel -y --force-yes
               then echo "axel installed"
            else echo "unable to install the axel. you are using sudo?" ; exit
            fi ;;
         n) echo "not possible usage apt-fast" ; exit ;;
    esac
fi

# If the user entered arguments contain upgrade, install, or dist-upgrade
if echo "$@" | grep -q "upgrade\|install\|dist-upgrade"; then
  echo "Working...";

  # Go into the directory apt-get normally puts downloaded packages
  cd /var/cache/apt/archives/;

  # Have apt-get print the information, including the URI's to the packages
  # Strip out the URI's, and download the packages with Axel for speediness
  # I found this regex elsewhere, showing how to manually strip package URI's you may need...thanks to whoever wrote it
  apt-get -y --print-uris $@ | egrep -o -e "(ht|f)tp://[^\']+" > apt-fast.list && cat apt-fast.list | xargs -l1 axel -a

  # Perform the user's requested action via apt-get
  apt-get $@;

  echo -e "\nDone! Verify that all packages were installed successfully. If errors are found, run apt-get clean as root and try again using apt-get directly.\n";

else
   apt-get $@;
fi
-------------------------
```

3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

4. Now just need run:

   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/apt-fast

   sudo apt-get install axel

Comment: How do I use this script? do I save it in a text editor and run it?